# why is this google apps script stopping halfway through?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm very new to google apps script (this is my first attempt) so if I've missed something obvious please go easy.

I have been given (reluctant) ownership of a spreadsheet at work, that needs to be refreshed every month.  I need to remove data on 31 sheets (named 1 through 31, not my idea and I'm not allowed to change the names), update dates and change weekend dates to have a red colour on the tabs.

The date changes are easy, I can update one cell and have everything else change based on that.  The remove data and update tab colours I figured I could do with a script.  In order to stop some numpties I work with doing it by "accident" I figured I would do it with an on edit command, when I edit the date cell (instead of adding a custom menu which would attract said numpties -  "oh, Shiny.  Must press").

Here is my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();

  if(sheetName == 'Daily Summary' && column == 8 && row == 7)
{
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("are you creating a new months absence diary?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == "YES"){
  for( var Tab=1; Tab<32; Tab++) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Tab);
 sheet.getRange('B6:D245').clearContent(); // clear preload, name and phone number columns
 sheet.getRange('I6:O245').clearContent(); // clear comments, sick type and paid hours
var date = sheet.getRange("M1").getValue();
if (date > 5) {
 sheet.setTabColor("ff0000"); // if weekend set tab to red
} else {
  sheet.setTabColor(null); // if not weekend set to no colour
}
}
}
}
}
```

when I edit the required cell, I get the popup as expected and it starts working, and works for the first 10 tabs, and then stops.

If I try to run it without the onEdit section it works (script incomeing)

```
function alertMessageYesNoButton() {
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("are you creating a new months absence diary?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == "YES"){
  for( var Tab=1; Tab<32; Tab++) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Tab);
 sheet.getRange('B6:D245').clearContent(); // clear preload, name and phone number columns
 sheet.getRange('I6:O245').clearContent(); // clear comments, sick type and paid hours
var date = sheet.getRange("M1").getValue();
if (date > 5) {
 sheet.setTabColor("ff0000"); // if weekend set tab to red
} else {
  sheet.setTabColor(null); // if not weekend set to no colour
}
}
}
}
```

any help on why it stops partway through when I add the onEdit would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It could be the fact that funtions that run from simple triggers will terminate after 30 seconds.  UI operations tend to be slow.

Comment: You could speed things up considerably if you would learn to use the event object

Comment: `functions that run from simple triggers will terminate after 30 seconds` [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). So, just to spell it out in case there was any confusion, @Cooper is suggesting that you create an installable `onEdit` trigger (**but not named "onEdit"**).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I somehow missed the 30 second limitation on the simple triggers.  I'll have to investigate the installable triggers.